# Rails ActiveRecord Multiple Levels of Association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm having a little trouble with querying multiple tables with different types of association. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sale, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :images, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

What would be the query to get all items relating to a sale with the ID 1, and then loop through all the images relating to each item returned?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can define `:through => :something` in a `has_many` association

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :images, :through => :items
end
```

and then simply query

```
Sale.find(1).images
```

Comment: It presents some issues, as that will not return images relevant to the item of which is currently in the loop (please see the below code) `<h2>Items in Sale</h2> <% if @sale.items.length > 0 %> <% @sale.items.each do |item| %> <p style="float: left; margin: 0; padding-left: 10px;"> <% @sale.images do |image| %> <%= image_tag image.photo.url(:thumb) %> <% end %> <b>Title:</b> <%= item.title%> </p> <% end %> <% else %> <p>No items listen in this sale</p> <% end %> <div style="clear:both;"></div>` Any further ideas?